# Creating new eng.tessdata file for custom font in Tesseract giving error

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line-interface, ocr, tesseract

Converted the PDF file into `.tiff` which is pretty straightforward

```
convert -depth 4 -density 300 -background white +matte eng.arial.pdf eng.arial.tiff
```

Then train tesseract for the `.tiff` file -

```
tesseract eng.arial.tiff eng.arial batch.nochop makebox
```

Then feed the .tiff file into tesseract -

```
tesseract eng.arial.tiff eng.arial.box nobatch box.train .stderr
```

Detect the Character set used -

```
unicharset_extractor *.box
```

But I am getting this error -

```
unicharset_extractor:./.libs/lt-unicharset_extractor.c:233: FATAL: couldn't find unicharset_extractor.
```

And it also happening for `mftraining` and `combine_tessdata` as well.

**UPDATE**

Ran unicharset_extractor on single box file and still doesn't work.

[image]

And it is not only with this command but also with `mftraining`, `cntraining` and `combine_tessdata`.

Comment: Which version of tesseract do you use? Are you using the latest version? I found [tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract) sources on GitHub. But there is no file `lt-unicharset_extractor.c`, just a [unicharset_extractor.cpp](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/master/training/unicharset_extractor.cpp) with currently just 160 lines.

Comment: @Mofi `tesseract 3.05.00dev`
 `leptonica-1.72`
  `libjpeg 9 : libpng 1.5.14 : libtiff 4.0.3 : zlib 1.2.5 : libopenjp2 2.1.0`

Comment: @Mofi yes it is working on the older version `3.02.00` but what about the new version.

Comment: Sorry, I'm very busy at the moment and don't have time to investigate an application which I don't have installed at all on my computers. It looks like you have detected an issue (bug) in tesseract 3.05.00 which should be reported to the developers of this open source project. Report an issue on the tesseract project page.

Comment: @Mofi, I think you should post that as the answer.  This is a very old question and that's the only answer that makes any sense.

Comment: @mjosh, did you ever find a solution to this problem?  Can you post an acceptable answer?

Comment: @jwdonahue I switched to older version